# Templated class fails taking other templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class that takes a reference to that template as single argument in the constrcutor. This works fine untill the template parameter becomes a class that is also templated. The compiler (VS 2008) gives me a couple of errors but I can't find out how to solve this...

EDIT
this is from the actual source :

```
PerlinNoise<> per;
RawPainter< PerlinNoise<> > pat(per);
TextureGenerator<RawPainter<PerlinNoise<> > genn(pat);
```

where PerlinNoise has default template parameters and both RawPainter and TextureGenerator take a reference (from type T) in the constructor

So, how can I make this work ?
It is probably a simple extra typename somewhere but I can't seem to figure it out.

thx

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: This should work, actually. Can you post the definition of `A`?

Comment: I'm sure the compiler tells you something more specific than "COMPILE ERROR". If you want this error solved you obviously should tell us what exact error you get.

Comment: yeah, I found out that the code I posted was to short as the last line of code should contain another template.. I edited it. The compile error is something like "syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'myB2'" and 'meB2 identifier not found' and a couple more complaining about missing ',' and '>' and ';'

Comment: The question has been substantially edited, but now it is obviously wrong: in the last line there are 3 `<` but only two `>`, calling for a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

```
 int pod = 5;
 B<int> myB(pod); //OK
```

This works. `B<int>` requires an `int&` to contstruct. Since `pod` is an int, it can trivially be converted into the correct type.

```
A<int> myA;
B< A< A<int> > > myB2(myA); //COMPILE ERROR
```

Well, this can't work. The constructor for `B< A< A< int > >  >` requires an `A< A< int > >` and you pass it an `A< int >`. There's no conversion available, so there's no way to get the right type to pass to the constructor.

Your compiler should have explained this to you. Mine did:

```
error: no matching function for call to B<A<A<int> > >::B(A<int>&)
note: candidates are:
note: B<T>::B(T&) [with T = A<A<int> >]
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from A<int> to A<A<int> >&
note: B<A<A<int> > >::B(const B<A<A<int> > >&)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from A<int> to const B<A<A<int> > >&
```

This is the give away: `no known conversion for argument 1 from A<int> to A<A<int> >&`. The last line tells you the compiler also tried to use an implicit copy constructor, but that failed too.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the correct reference into the constructor:

```
A<A<int> > myAA;
B< A< A<int> > > myB3(myAA);
```